# XSL - How can I properly concatenate node values into one formatted node value

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, hl7-v2

I'm trying to concatenate multiple OBX.3, OBX.5, and OBX.6 values to the end of a specific OBX.5 field.  What I have written works, but not in the way that I want it to.

For example, I want this source:

```
OBX|1|TX|2080^Diagnosis||Sinus rhythm~Right axis deviation~Right atrial enlargement~Possible Ventricular preexcitation~Biventricular hypertrophy~~When compared with ECG of 17-JAN-2020 13:15, there is no significant change.~~~Confirmed by DOCTOR MD, DOCTOR (174) on 1/26/2020 10:57:01 PM||||||F 
OBX|2|ST|552^Ventricular Rate||126|BPM|||||F 
OBX|3|ST|554^P-R Interval||88|ms|||||F
OBX|4|ST|555^QRS Duration||90|ms|||||F 
OBX|5|ST|556^Q-T Interval||380|ms|||||F 
OBX|6|ST|557^QTC Calculation(Bazett)||550|ms|||||F
```

or xml version:

```
                        <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
                            <OBX>
                                <OBX.1>1</OBX.1>
                                <OBX.2>TX</OBX.2>
                                <OBX.3>
                                    <CWE.1>2080</CWE.1>
                                    <CWE.2>Diagnosis</CWE.2>
                                </OBX.3>
                                <OBX.5>Sinus rhythm</OBX.5>
                                <OBX.5>Right axis deviation</OBX.5>
                                <OBX.5>Right atrial enlargement</OBX.5>
                                <OBX.5>Possible Ventricular preexcitation</OBX.5>
                                <OBX.5>Biventricular hypertrophy</OBX.5>
                                <OBX.5>When compared with ECG of 17-JAN-2020 13:15, there is no significant change.</OBX.5>
                                <OBX.5>Confirmed by DOCTOR MD, DOCTOR (174) on 1/26/2020 10:57:01 PM</OBX.5>
                                <OBX.11>F</OBX.11>
                            </OBX>
                        </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
                        <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
                            <OBX>
                                <OBX.1>2</OBX.1>
                                <OBX.2>ST</OBX.2>
                                <OBX.3>
                                    <CWE.1>552</CWE.1>
                                    <CWE.2>Ventricular Rate</CWE.2>
                                </OBX.3>
                                <OBX.5>126</OBX.5>
                                <OBX.6>
                                    <CWE.1>BPM</CWE.1>
                                </OBX.6>
                                <OBX.11>F</OBX.11>
                            </OBX>
                        </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
                        <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
                            <OBX>
                                <OBX.1>3</OBX.1>
                                <OBX.2>ST</OBX.2>
                                <OBX.3>
                                    <CWE.1>554</CWE.1>
                                    <CWE.2>P-R Interval</CWE.2>
                                </OBX.3>
                                <OBX.5>88</OBX.5>
                                <OBX.6>
                                    <CWE.1>ms</CWE.1>
                                </OBX.6>
                                <OBX.11>F</OBX.11>
                            </OBX>
                        </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
                        <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
                            <OBX>
                                <OBX.1>4</OBX.1>
                                <OBX.2>ST</OBX.2>
                                <OBX.3>
                                    <CWE.1>555</CWE.1>
                                    <CWE.2>QRS Duration</CWE.2>
                                </OBX.3>
                                <OBX.5>90</OBX.5>
                                <OBX.6>
                                    <CWE.1>ms</CWE.1>
                                </OBX.6>
                                <OBX.11>F</OBX.11>
                            </OBX>
                        </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
                        <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
                            <OBX>
                                <OBX.1>5</OBX.1>
                                <OBX.2>ST</OBX.2>
                                <OBX.3>
                                    <CWE.1>556</CWE.1>
                                    <CWE.2>Q-T Interval</CWE.2>
                                </OBX.3>
                                <OBX.5>380</OBX.5>
                                <OBX.6>
                                    <CWE.1>ms</CWE.1>
                                </OBX.6>
                                <OBX.11>F</OBX.11>
                            </OBX>
                        </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
                        <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
                            <OBX>
                                <OBX.1>6</OBX.1>
                                <OBX.2>ST</OBX.2>
                                <OBX.3>
                                    <CWE.1>557</CWE.1>
                                    <CWE.2>QTC Calculation(Bazett)</CWE.2>
                                </OBX.3>
                                <OBX.5>550</OBX.5>
                                <OBX.6>
                                    <CWE.1>ms</CWE.1>
                                </OBX.6>
                                <OBX.11>F</OBX.11>
                            </OBX>
                        </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
                        <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
                            <OBX>
                                <OBX.1>7</OBX.1>
                                <OBX.2>RP</OBX.2>
                                <OBX.3>
                                    <CWE.1>APPWebURL</CWE.1>
                                </OBX.3>
                                <OBX.5>
                                    <RP.1>http://SERVERSQL1:8989/appcripts/appweb.dll?RetrieveTestByDateTime?PatientID=123456789&amp;Date=23-01-2020&amp;Time=12%3a21%3a05%3a00&amp;TestType=ECG&amp;Site=1&amp;OutputType=PDF&amp;Ext=PDF</RP.1>
                                </OBX.5>
                                <OBX.11>F</OBX.11>
                            </OBX>
                        </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
```

To look like this:

```
OBX|1|TX|2082^Diagnosis||Sinus rhythm~Right axis deviation~Right atrial enlargement~Possible Ventricular preexcitation~Biventricular hypertrophy~When compared with ECG of 17-JAN-2020 13:15, there is no significant change.~Confirmed by DOCTOR MD, DOCTOR (174) on 1/26/2020 10:57:01 PM~Ventricular Rate: 126 BPM~P-R Interval: 88 ms~QRS Duration: 90 ms~Q-T Interval: 380 ms~QTC Calculation(Bazett): 550 ms
```

However, i can only get it to look like this:

```
OBX|1|TX|2082^Diagnosis||Sinus rhythm Right axis deviation Right atrial enlargement Possible Ventricular preexcitation Biventricular hypertrophy When compared with ECG of 17-JAN-2020 13:15, there is no significant change. Confirmed by DOCTOR MD, DOCTOR (174) on 1/26/2020 10:57:01 PM\R\Ventricular Rate P-R Interval QRS Duration Q-T Interval QTC Calculation(Bazett)\R\126 88 90 380 550\R\BPM ms ms ms ms
```

Here is my code:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="ORU_R01.OBSERVATION[OBX/OBX.2!='RP']">
        <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
        <xsl:variable name="rpt">
            <xsl:value-of select="//OBX[OBX.2='TX']/OBX.5" />
        </xsl:variable>                                                         
            <xsl:if test="OBX/OBX.2 = 'TX'">
                <OBX>
                    <OBX.1>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'1'" />
                    </OBX.1>
                    <OBX.2>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'TX'" />
                    </OBX.2>
                    <OBX.3>
                        <CWE.1>
                            <xsl:value-of select="'2082'" />
                        </CWE.1>
                        <CWE.2>
                            <xsl:value-of select="'Diagnosis'" />
                        </CWE.2>
                    </OBX.3>
                    <OBX.5>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$rpt" />
                    </OBX.5>
                    <OBX.5>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//OBX[OBX.2='ST']/OBX.3/CWE.2" />
                    </OBX.5>
                    <OBX.5>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//OBX[OBX.2='ST']/OBX.5" />
                    </OBX.5>
                    <OBX.5>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//OBX[OBX.2='ST']/OBX.6/CWE.1" />
                    </OBX.5>                                                                        
                </OBX>
            </xsl:if>
        </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: It's hard to guess without input source, but you already have a problem mixing an `xsl:for-each` instruction with absolute location path like `//OBX/OBX.2`

Comment: @Alejandro, I have edited my text for better representation.  The input source is provided.  The `xsl:for-each` is because the OBX segments are repeating.

Comment: It is still confuse because the input source is HL7 v.2 (text) and your code is an XSLT stylesheet more suited for HL7 v.3 (XML)

Comment: @Alejandro I added the XML and updated my coding. Still get the same result.

Comment: You are iterating over **six** `ORU_R01.OBSERVATION[OBX/OBX.2!='RP']` outputting an `ORU_R01.OBSERVATION` for each one. But only for one that `OBX/OBX.2 = 'TX'` your stylesheet outputs an `OBX` with fixed data and those from the **first** `//OBX[OBX.2='ST']`

Comment: @Alejandro I only need one OBX output, but it needs to have the output of EACH OBX segment that contains '//OBX[OBX.2='ST']' to be appended to the end of that ONE OBX segment. So how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="*[ORU_R01.OBSERVATION]">
        <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
            <OBX>
                <OBX.1>1</OBX.1>
                <OBX.2>TX</OBX.2>
                <OBX.3>
                    <CWE.1>2082</CWE.1>
                    <CWE.2>Diagnosis</CWE.2>
                </OBX.3>
                <xsl:copy-of 
                    select="ORU_R01.OBSERVATION/OBX[OBX.2='TX']/OBX.5"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="ORU_R01.OBSERVATION/OBX[OBX.2='ST']">
                    <OBX.5>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(OBX.3/CWE.2,':'),OBX.5,OBX.6/CWE.1"/>
                    </OBX.5>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </OBX>
        </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Whit this input:

```
<root> 
  <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION> 
    <OBX> 
      <OBX.1>1</OBX.1>  
      <OBX.2>TX</OBX.2>  
      <OBX.3> 
        <CWE.1>2080</CWE.1>  
        <CWE.2>Diagnosis</CWE.2> 
      </OBX.3>  
      <OBX.5>Sinus rhythm</OBX.5>  
      <OBX.5>Right axis deviation</OBX.5>  
      <OBX.5>Right atrial enlargement</OBX.5>  
      <OBX.5>Possible Ventricular preexcitation</OBX.5>  
      <OBX.5>Biventricular hypertrophy</OBX.5>  
      <OBX.5>When compared with ECG of 17-JAN-2020 13:15, there is no significant change.</OBX.5>  
      <OBX.5>Confirmed by DOCTOR MD, DOCTOR (174) on 1/26/2020 10:57:01 PM</OBX.5>  
      <OBX.11>F</OBX.11> 
    </OBX> 
  </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>  
  <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION> 
    <OBX> 
      <OBX.1>2</OBX.1>  
      <OBX.2>ST</OBX.2>  
      <OBX.3> 
        <CWE.1>552</CWE.1>  
        <CWE.2>Ventricular Rate</CWE.2> 
      </OBX.3>  
      <OBX.5>126</OBX.5>  
      <OBX.6> 
        <CWE.1>BPM</CWE.1> 
      </OBX.6>  
      <OBX.11>F</OBX.11> 
    </OBX> 
  </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>  
  <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION> 
    <OBX> 
      <OBX.1>3</OBX.1>  
      <OBX.2>ST</OBX.2>  
      <OBX.3> 
        <CWE.1>554</CWE.1>  
        <CWE.2>P-R Interval</CWE.2> 
      </OBX.3>  
      <OBX.5>88</OBX.5>  
      <OBX.6> 
        <CWE.1>ms</CWE.1> 
      </OBX.6>  
      <OBX.11>F</OBX.11> 
    </OBX> 
  </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>  
  <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION> 
    <OBX> 
      <OBX.1>4</OBX.1>  
      <OBX.2>ST</OBX.2>  
      <OBX.3> 
        <CWE.1>555</CWE.1>  
        <CWE.2>QRS Duration</CWE.2> 
      </OBX.3>  
      <OBX.5>90</OBX.5>  
      <OBX.6> 
        <CWE.1>ms</CWE.1> 
      </OBX.6>  
      <OBX.11>F</OBX.11> 
    </OBX> 
  </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>  
  <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION> 
    <OBX> 
      <OBX.1>5</OBX.1>  
      <OBX.2>ST</OBX.2>  
      <OBX.3> 
        <CWE.1>556</CWE.1>  
        <CWE.2>Q-T Interval</CWE.2> 
      </OBX.3>  
      <OBX.5>380</OBX.5>  
      <OBX.6> 
        <CWE.1>ms</CWE.1> 
      </OBX.6>  
      <OBX.11>F</OBX.11> 
    </OBX> 
  </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>  
  <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION> 
    <OBX> 
      <OBX.1>6</OBX.1>  
      <OBX.2>ST</OBX.2>  
      <OBX.3> 
        <CWE.1>557</CWE.1>  
        <CWE.2>QTC Calculation(Bazett)</CWE.2> 
      </OBX.3>  
      <OBX.5>550</OBX.5>  
      <OBX.6> 
        <CWE.1>ms</CWE.1> 
      </OBX.6>  
      <OBX.11>F</OBX.11> 
    </OBX> 
  </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>  
  <ORU_R01.OBSERVATION> 
    <OBX> 
      <OBX.1>7</OBX.1>  
      <OBX.2>RP</OBX.2>  
      <OBX.3> 
        <CWE.1>APPWebURL</CWE.1> 
      </OBX.3>  
      <OBX.5> 
        <RP.1>http://SERVERSQL1:8989/appcripts/appweb.dll?RetrieveTestByDateTime?PatientID=123456789&amp;Date=23-01-2020&amp;Time=12%3a21%3a05%3a00&amp;TestType=ECG&amp;Site=1&amp;OutputType=PDF&amp;Ext=PDF</RP.1> 
      </OBX.5>  
      <OBX.11>F</OBX.11> 
    </OBX> 
  </ORU_R01.OBSERVATION> 
</root>
```

Output:

```
<ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
   <OBX>
      <OBX.1>1</OBX.1>
      <OBX.2>TX</OBX.2>
      <OBX.3>
         <CWE.1>2082</CWE.1>
         <CWE.2>Diagnosis</CWE.2>
      </OBX.3>
      <OBX.5>Sinus rhythm</OBX.5>
      <OBX.5>Right axis deviation</OBX.5>
      <OBX.5>Right atrial enlargement</OBX.5>
      <OBX.5>Possible Ventricular preexcitation</OBX.5>
      <OBX.5>Biventricular hypertrophy</OBX.5>
      <OBX.5>When compared with ECG of 17-JAN-2020 13:15, there is no significant change.</OBX.5>
      <OBX.5>Confirmed by DOCTOR MD, DOCTOR (174) on 1/26/2020 10:57:01 PM</OBX.5>
      <OBX.5>Ventricular Rate: 126 BPM</OBX.5>
      <OBX.5>P-R Interval: 88 ms</OBX.5>
      <OBX.5>QRS Duration: 90 ms</OBX.5>
      <OBX.5>Q-T Interval: 380 ms</OBX.5>
      <OBX.5>QTC Calculation(Bazett): 550 ms</OBX.5>
   </OBX>
</ORU_R01.OBSERVATION>
```

Test in [here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexji3)

**Do note**: you can copy elements as well as use a literal result element; there is no need for the `xsl:value-of` instruction when outputting literal text nodes; `xsl:value-of` semantic have change between XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 and now it can also output sequence.

Comment: Fantastic!  That works (except I removed the template lines since it's already being called at the beginning of the complete transformer file)!!  Thanks a ton @Alejandro!